# Swift: Не могу подгрузить данные из БД в TableView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, tableview

Добрый день.
Подскажите в чём проблема: есть такой код

```
class ContentController: UITableViewController {

    @IBOutlet var tabContent: UITableView!

    var k:Int=0
    var contents = [[Content]]()
    var cont_1=[Content]()   

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var query = SCQuery(collection: "content")
        query.doesNotExist("id_up")
        query.find{ (success,error,result) in
            for document in (result)! {
                let doc=document.value as! [String:Any]
                self.cont_1.append(Content(item:doc["name"] as! String,key:doc["_id"] as! String))
            }
            self.contents.append(self.cont_1)
        }
        tabContent.reloadData()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return contents[k].count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell=tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text=contents[k][indexPath.row].item
        return cell
    }
}
```

Но при выполнении замыкания `query.find{...}` в методе `viewDidLoad()` на выходе переменная `contents` и `cont_1` остаются пустыми (хотя `self.contents` и `self.cont_1` заполнены). В результате

```
return contents[k].count
```

возвращает ошибку `index out of range`, т.к. массив `contents` пуст. Почему так и как это исправить? Вообще если добавить в замыкание вывод элементов `self.contents`, то получается что сначала происходит `return contents[k].count`, а уже после выводятся заполненный массив `self.contents`. Как мне заполнить массив contents, в каком методе лучше это сделать и всё сделать правильно? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Что Вы имеете в виду под `в методе viewDidLoad() на выходе переменная contents и cont_1 остаются пустыми (хотя self.contents и self.cont_1 заполнены)`? Здесь у Вас проблема в работе с потоками, т.к. обращение к данным происходит раньше, они еще не получены.

Comment: А как сделать так, чтобы сперва были получены данные? Запустить метод `query.find{...}` в потоке `main`? Я пробовал запускать `query.find{...}` в потоке таким способом:

`let queue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
queue.async{
query.find{...}
...
}` Но это тоже не дало результатов.

Comment: проблема в том, что вы по сути делаете парсинг в тоже время когда и грузится таблица, вот и получается, что массив пустой. Я бы предложил перенести вычисления во viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear. Показать индикатор загрузки на время парсинга. Ну или же сделать все вычисления до перехода на нужный контроллера, и передать туда уже все данные. По сути контроллер не должен заниматься вычислениями, лучше сделать viewModel для таких целей!

Comment: А можно поподробнее про `viewModel`?Как создать и использовать?

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, нельзя вот так грубо указывать contents[k].count. Неизвестно же что в массиве. Нужна хотя бы проверка:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return contents.count > 0 ? contents[k].count : 0 //ну и k проверяйте в соответствии как будете ее использовать
}
```

Далее, query.find{...} и так выполняется в отдельном потоке. Поэтому по завершении необходимо обновить таблицу, по Вашему коду:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var query = SCQuery(collection: "content")
    query.doesNotExist("id_up")
    query.find{ (success,error,result) in
        for document in (result)! {
            let doc=document.value as! [String:Any]
            self.cont_1.append(Content(item:doc["name"] as! String,key:doc["_id"] as! String))
        }
        self.contents.append(self.cont_1)
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.tabContent.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую сделать так.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за ответ. В итоге проблема заключалась именно в грубом указателе `contents[k].count` - добавил условие и всё заработало даже без использования потока `main`. Главное добавить метод `reloadData()`. Единственное хочу уточнить - нужно ли всё таки вызывать метод `reloadData()` в потоке `main`?

Comment: @snowty все операции, где каким-либо боком задействован UI нужно выполнять из главного потока

Comment: У меня такой вопрос (возможно, стоило создать его как отдельный, но он по этому же коду) - как я могу полученный массив `cont_1` сохранить в кеше, чтобы при следующем запуске приложения не пришлось в очередной раз грузить эти данные?

Comment: @snowty А зачем?